# Why should i use guice-hk2-bridge?

Tags: java, jersey, guice, hk2

I'm sorry for the stupid question, but i really searched for an answer for this question and didn't get a clearly one.

I know that jersey uses hk2 as default DI and because hk2 is performance loss, the alternative DI is Guice which is better, we need to configure jersey to use Guice using guice-hk2-bridge.

The question is WHY ?, why we need to configure jersey ?, why we can't just use `com.google.inject.Inject` instead of `javax.inject.Inject`, using Guice by importing only the `com.google.inject` package ?

What is so important about this bridge ?, i tried to work without guice-hk2-bridge and it worked perfectly to me... I'm sure there is something that i misunderstand..

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm not sure how much experience you have programming with annotations, but just to let you know, there is no magic behind them. They are simply metadata, and it is up to the framework to decide what to do with that metadata. For you to say "why can't we switch `javax.inject.Inject` for `com.google.inject.Inject` and make Guice work?" shows a lack of understanding of this concept.

Any DI framework is built around a container to hold all the services bound to that system. For HK2, the container is the `ServiceLocator`, for Spring, the container is the `ApplicationContext`, and for Guice, the container is the `Injector`. That being said, Jersey is *tightly* coupled with HK2<sup>1</sup>. What this means is that because HK2 is tied to the `ServiceLocator` container, Jersey is also tied to this `ServiceLocator`. So when a service is looked up in a Jersey application, it will be looked up via the `ServiceLocator`. Take for example the following

```
@Path("customers")
public class CustomerResource {
    @Inject
    private CustomerService service;

    @GET
    public List<Customer> findAll() {
        return service.findAll();
    }
}
```

With the above, somewhere under the hood, the following (in pseudocode) is going on to get the `CustomerService` to inject into the `CustomerResource`

```
ServiceLocator locator = getServiceLocator();
CustomerService service = locator.getService(CustomerService.class);
```

When we have Jersey create (manage the lifecycle of) the resource (the `CustomerResource`), even the resource is a service bound in the `ServiceLocator`. This is what I mean that everything in Jersey is tightly coupled with HK2 and the `ServiceLocator`.

So in order for us to introduce another DI framework, we need to tap into the `ServiceLocator`. What the bridge does is tie the Guice `Injector` to the HK2 `ServiceLocator` so that the services in the Guice `Injector` can be discovered through the `ServiceLocator`. If the `CustomerService` were a service bound to the Guice `Injector`, then what would happen is that Jersey would look for it in the `ServiceLocator`, and the locator would look in the `Injector` for it. This is wha the bridge does.

---

<sub>1. Starting version 2.26, Jersey actually breaks ties with the HK2 in being tightly coupled. It's complicated to explain, but in short, we still need to use HK2 with Jersey even though they are no longer tightly coupled.</sub>

Comment: I'm not so familiar with annotation programming,
so i do have lack of understanding of this concept.
But i still can't understand, 
if i'm using com.google.inject.Inject instead of javax.inject.Inject and i'm not using guice-h2k-bridge,
and i write my own class named Users, in Users.java i'm injecting EmailHandaler.java via com.google.inject.Inject,
EmailHandler will injected by Guice ?

Comment: The only way it would work if both are bound to the Guice container. If EmailHandler is a Jersey resource class, and you bound this and the Users with the Guice container, you could get an instance of the EmailHandler through the Guice Injector and register that instance with Jersey. It would work this way. This is the _only_ way it would work.

Comment: Ok, so if i manage all my resources from Guice container,
bind all my resources with Guice and use com.google.inject.Inject
and i'm not using Jersey resources, it will work ?.
Can i read between the lines and say that i should use Guice-HK2-Bridge
*only* if i'm using my (Guice binded) resources *with* Jersey resources (which i don't know what they are) ?.
So only if i combine with my resources and Jersey resources i need to use that bridge ?

Comment: Your `@Path` Classe are Jersey resources. You can bind these with Guice. Then get an instance of it from the Guice container. And register that instance with the Jersey application. This is what I mean.

Comment: How can i bind those resources from Guice?

Comment: Search for tutorials on how to use Guice.

Comment: You should note that this approach is very limited. It's not something I would recommend doing. I am simply answering your question of how it could be done.

Comment: thank you! i will bind resources with Guice and simply do all my binding with Guice..